# How to correctly use colon?

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis, semicolons, colons

I have the following sentence:

> The company will be oriented towards the development of three types of
>   products: video games, video animations and digital marketing for
>   which it will make use of a flexible and easy-to-grow type of
>   organization.

I feel there is a grammatical error in terms of how the colon is implemented.

Comment: What [research](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/numbers.htm#lists) have you done?

Comment: I stumbled upon this article http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/colon.html

Comment: See the following questions and answers for more detail: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/186432/use-of-semi-colons-vs-commas-when-listing-items-with-colons https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2503/is-it-proper-usage-to-replace-a-comma-in-a-list-with-a-semi-colon-in-this-situat https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/108218/should-i-use-commas-or-semi-colons-in-this-multi-item-list-within-a-sentence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with the use of the colon, but I would use two sentences:

*"The company will be oriented towards the development of three types of products: video games, video animations and digital marketing.  It will make use of a flexible and easy-to-grow type of organization."*

Answer (score 0):

You are using the colon correctly.

Comment: Thanks, but is the added content after the colon correct to remain part of that sentence?

Comment: A good answer on EL&U will explain why it is correct.

Comment: The content after the colon does not gave to be a complete sentence because you already have at least one complete thought.